# rtl8191SEvB wireless in openSuse

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, thinkpad, opensuse-11.4

Having bad luck with preinstalled Win7 on my new Lenovo T510, I decided to install Suse 11.4.
Everything worked out-of the box, except for wireless card. lspci told me the card's name:
[Realtek semiconductors etc... RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller (rev 10)]
hwinfo doesn't list it.
Is there any method to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my netbook (no kernel driver for RTL9191SEvB) running Debian. First make sure that you have the realtek firmwares installed (in Debian the package is `firmware-realtek`), they *may* contain the correct firmwares.

If that fails, just go to http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2302 and grab the Linux driver. Extract it using your regular archive tool, open a terminal inside that extracted directory and run (as root):

```
make
make install
modprobe r8192se_pci
```

(Yes the driver is for RTL8192 but works really fine with this card too, see http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=609784). That's it, your card should be running. If the driver doesn't load automatically at startup, you can add a `r8192se_pci` line in /etc/modules. Hope it helps.